# Date when record was created in mysql datatabase

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in which I have birthdate , age location and Score and I want to retrieve the count of number of records created between two dates where score is not null and there is no time stamp field.

How can I do it if there is no time stamp field.

Is there any meta data and if it is , how can I run the query?

Comment: Nope, can't be done. You'd need to have stored the date it was entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE BIRTHDATE BETWEEN 'DATE1' AND 'DATE2' 
AND SCORE IS NOT NULL AND TIMESTAMP IS NULL;
```

Add a column `timestamp` to the existing table, with default value as `NULL`, and query the above statement, it should work.
Whenever you add a column, to a table already having records, the corresponding values are blank for that new column, for existing records.

Comment: : how can I add like a time stamp column using query so that it will automaticaly store the date when record was created? I mean if there is any query to update table property with new column ?

Comment: you can use `ALTER TABLE` for adding column -- http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php

Comment: and for updating table, use `INSERT` with a `timestamp` as `NOW()`. so for eg. `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES ('20120420', 25, 'New York, NOW());`

Comment: its updating DB with POST ajax calls so I can not use the insert command. though I can alter the table and add time stamp as one column like this-->  alter table table-name add column column-name timestamp;   but will it automaticaly update the date when record will be created in that row for that time stamp field ?

Comment: no, it will not automatically do so, you would have to update the query that is used to insert/create records. why cant you use INSERT via ajax post?

Comment: accept the answer, that works best for you, helps us get some points :)

Comment: just found out that you can add value default Null when u create a columnn with timestamp property.

Comment: like i mentioned in my answer :)

Comment: SOrry I mean to say YOU CAN NOT add value NULL as default

Comment: i dont think so, read the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'DateRecord'

Comment: I was trying to add Null as Default value but its not allowing me to do

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp to your tables

Comment: While this is excellent advice, it won't help with data that's already in the table.

Comment: @Muhammet Well yes thats a good advice, I should add timestamp for future solution but as @ andrew said what about the data thats already in the table

Comment: @Muhammet what if I want to add time stamp to exisitng table? how should I do it so that it will just add a column date and I can see when record was created?

Answer (score 0):

Echoed here as other users have noted.

Because you have no date reference field in the database, you can't pull out records that match one or that are between two dates.

Your best bet from here on in, is to add a date field and then make sure when data is written to the DB, you insert a date/datetime using [mysql now() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now). There are a few different ways to achieve it, but this is probably the easiest:

```
mysql_query("
   INSERT INTO users (first, last, whenadded) 
   VALUES ('$first', '$last', now())
";
```